# Artifacts after Radon Transform across image diagonals?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using the built-in radon function from the Image Processing Toolbox in MATLAB. Until today, I had been using some custom functions that gave me the results I expected. Particularly, I am developing a mathematical model that retrieves the projections of a Point Spread Function (PSF) in several directions (the baseline is 0/45/90/135 degrees).

I have prepared a really simple example that will show the problems I am experimenting:

```
I = zeros(1000,1000);
I(250:750, 250:750) = 1;
theta = [0 45 90 135];
[R,xp] = radon(I,theta);
figure;plot(R);legend('0°','45°','90°','135°');
```

If you run the example, you will see that the plot for 45/135° (diagonals) shows an artifact shaped as a saw-tooth along the curve. At first I thought it had to do with the sampling grid I am using (even number of points). However, when using a grid with an odd number of points, the problem remains there. I do not quite understand this result, since the radon transform is just a cumulative integral across several directions. Therefore, I should not get this "saw-tooth" pattern.

I am really confused about the result. Has anybody experimented the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is the aliasing artifact when you use a simple forward projector, which I believe is what implemented in the `randon()` function. To remove this artifact, you need to increase the number of samplings (`randon()` probably uses the same number of samplings of the phantom, you might want to increase that number to as least double the number of phantom samplings), or implement a better forward projector, such as driven-driven projector which is used in GE's CT image reconstruction software.